# to attach an event to each element of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made several icon, and on their mouse hover they should do something. Now, I have made an array of my Icons, but as I apply each() to the set, it does not work:

So i need the following block of code to attach a hover event to each element of the set.

```
var icon_set = new Array('.icon-online', '.icon-save', '.icon-sms',
    '.icon-access', '.icon-support');
icon_set.each(function () {
    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        img.stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: *"it does not work"* isn't a really good problem description.

Comment: `icon_set` is a plain JavaScript array, not a jQuery object, so you can't use the `.each()` jQuery function. Use `jQuery.each()` instead: `$.each(icon_set, function() {...});`.

Comment: You can just attach it to them all at once `$('.icon-online, .icon-save, .icon-sms, .icon-access, .icon-support').mouseleave(function() {...});`

Comment: Where is `img` defined in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var icon_set = new Array('.icon-online', '.icon-save', '.icon-sms',
    '.icon-access', '.icon-support');
$(icon_set.join()).mouseleave(function () {
    img.stop().fadeOut();
});
```

---

`icon_set.each(function () {` --> `.each()` doesn't work with array

Use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) , [array.forEach(callback[, thisArg])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for array.

Comment: Why should the OP try that? What's the problem with their code?

Comment: @FelixKling  array.each() was the problem. PS: looks like your questions were to ask for more explaination

Answer (score 4):

`icon_set` is a raw JavaScript `Array`. It doesn't have an `each` method. Use `Array.prototype.forEach` or `$.each` and wrap each array element with `$();`

```
icon_set.forEach(function (el) {
    $(el).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

or

```
$.each(icon_set, function(index, el) {
  $(el).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut();
  });
});
```

And prefer using the array literal syntax(`[]`) over the `Array` constructor

```
['.icon-online', '.icon-save', 
 '.icon-sms','.icon-access', '.icon-support'].forEach(yourMouseleaveHandler);
```

Comment: Also img is not defined it should be $(this).stop().fateOut();

Answer (score 1):

If all your icons have a classname that begin with `icon-` you can use this [Jquery Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('*[className^="icon-"]').mouseleave(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

PS: It will select all icons which begin with `icon-`. It depends, you may/may not want that.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, why not give those images another class which is the same for all, then your selector becomes much simpler, i.e for a new class of `myImgs`.

```
$('.myImgs').mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```